# Garbage printing in string convert from Streambuffer

Tags: c++, garbage

I'm making a simulator of C++ Client/Server TCP using Boost::Asio library.

Here is part of my code:

Client:

```
std::string option;
std::getline(std::cin, option);
option.push_back('\r');
option.push_back('\n');
boost::asio::write(client_socket, boost::asio::buffer(option));
```

Server:

```
boost::asio::streambuf received;
boost::asio::read_until(socket, received, "\r\n");
char number[7];
recieved.sgetn(number, 7);
std::cout << "The entered number is: " << number << std::endl;
```

(I included only the problematic code)

My problem is garbage values are included in the `char[] number`, like this for input `1234567`:

[image]

How can I fix this issue?

Comment: You should use string to store number and resize it using the number of bytes read from `read_until`'s return value. Then you wouldn't have to deal with all the `\0` crap.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to null terminate your string, which is not done by you.

```
char number[7]; //you need additional allocation for '\0'
```

use

```
char number[8];
```

Comment: As I said in my post, it would problaby be an easy error.
Thank you very much to answer me!
I was too borried about the sgetn and I didn't saw the more easy thing!

Answer (score 1):

```
char number[8];

recieved.sgetn(number, 7);

number[7] = '\0'
```

Comment: doesn't `sgetn()` include null termination?

Comment: I really don't know, but I think he takes the number of chars passed.

Comment: As I said in my post, it would problaby be an easy error.
Thank you very much to answer me!
I was too borried about the sgetn and I didn't saw the more easy thing!